# robot_state_broadcaster and multiple robots

Tags: ros2

I have a ROS2/Gazebo/Python project for 6 DOF robotic arm. It works, using joint_state_broadcaster and joint_trajectory_controller.

```
def generate_launch_description():

arm_core_file_name = get_package_share_directory('arm_02') + '/description/arm.urdf.xacro'

# Robot State Publisher 
robot_state_publisher = Node(
    package ='robot_state_publisher',
    executable ='robot_state_publisher',
    name ='robot_state_publisher',
    output ='both',
    parameters =[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro', ' ', arm_core_file_name])}])


# Spawn the robot in Gazebo
spawn_entity = Node(
    package ='gazebo_ros', 
    executable ='spawn_entity.py', 
    arguments = ['-entity', 'armA', '-topic', 'robot_description'],
    output ='screen')

# Gazebo   
world_file_name = 'empty.world'
world = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('arm_02'), '../worlds', world_file_name)
gazebo_node = ExecuteProcess(cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', world,'-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'], output='screen')

# load and START the controllers in launch file

joint_state_broadcaster = ExecuteProcess(
    cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'start','joint_state_broadcaster'],
    output='screen')

# joint_state_publisher_gui = Node(package  ='joint_state_publisher_gui',
#                                 executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
#                                 output    ='screen',
#                                 name      ='joint_state_publisher_gui')

joint_trajectory_controller = ExecuteProcess( 
    cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'start', 'joint_trajectory_controller'], 
    output='screen')

rviz_config_file = get_package_share_directory('arm_02') + "/rviz/armA.rviz"
rviz_node = Node(package    ='rviz2',
                 executable ='rviz2',
                 name       ='rviz2',
                 output     ='log',
                 arguments  =['-d', rviz_config_file])

gazebo_exit_event_handler = RegisterEventHandler(
    event_handler=OnProcessExit(
        target_action=gazebo_node,
        on_exit=EmitEvent(event=Shutdown(reason='gazebo exited'))))

rviz_exit_event_handler = RegisterEventHandler(
    event_handler=OnProcessExit(
        target_action=rviz_node,
        on_exit=EmitEvent(event=Shutdown(reason='rviz exited'))))

return LaunchDescription([robot_state_publisher, spawn_entity, 
    gazebo_node, joint_state_broadcaster, joint_trajectory_controller,
    rviz_node, #joint_state_publisher_gui,
    gazebo_exit_event_handler, rviz_exit_event_handler])
```

Now, I want to create two such arms in the same world. And I cannot figure it out. I can pass namespace to robot_state_publisher and spawner:

```
robots = [
    {'name': 'armA',  'x_pos': 0.0, 'y_pos': 0.0, 'z_pos': 0.01, 'urdf': armA_urdf_file_name  },
    {'name': 'gripA', 'x_pos': 0.0, 'y_pos': 0.5, 'z_pos': 0.01, 'urdf': gripA_urdf_file_name }
]

spawn_robots_cmds = []
for robot in robots:

    robot_state_publisher_cmd = Node(
        package ='robot_state_publisher',
        executable ='robot_state_publisher',
        name = 'robot_state_publisher',
        output ='both',
        namespace = robot['name'],
        remappings = [] if robot['name'] == "" else
            [
                ('/tf', '/' + robot['name'] + '/tf'),
                ('/tf_static', '/' + robot['name'] + '/tf_static'),
            ],
        parameters =[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro', ' ', robot['urdf']])}]
    )
    spawn_robots_cmds.append(robot_state_publisher_cmd)

    start_robot_cmd = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
        arguments=
        [
            '-topic', "robot_description" if robot['name'] == "" else robot['name'] + "/robot_description", 
            '-entity', 'armA',
            '-robot_namespace', robot['name'],
        ],
        
        remappings = [] if robot['name'] == "" else
            [
                ('/tf', '/tf/' + robot['name']),
                ('/tf_static', '/tf_static/' + robot['name']),                                  
            ],
        output='screen')
    spawn_robots_cmds.append(start_robot_cmd)
```

But I do not know what to do with joint_state_broadcaster and joint_trajectory_controller: looks like ExecuteProcess doesn't accept namespaces.

Also, I am not sure if I have to use namespaces also in URDF and in config files (and if yes, then how?)

I use ROS2 Galactic. Please help.

Comment: Uhm, the tag says "Please ask ROS 2 related questions on https://robotics.stackexchange.com from now on."

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Full code at [enter link description here](https://robotics.snowcron.com), in a "multiple robots" section.